# Подскажите как правильно обрабатывать JSON данные в jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Впервые столкнулся с обработкой json данных. 
Нашел простой пример и вроде бы разобрался. Вопрос только как обработать вложенные массив в данных?

Сами данные JSON для примера вот такие, вся проблема в обработки данных "items":

```
{   
"total": 2,
"module": "content",
"method": "getComplectItems",
"items": {
    "item": {
        "0": {
            "ide": "1",
            "namesmall": "11namr3rfd1",             
            "group": "1gr1"
        },

        "1": {
            "ide": "2",
            "namesmall": "222namr3rfd1",                
            "group": "2gr1"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Обрабатываю кодом:

```
$.getJSON('http://online.fteplo.ru/udata://content/getComplectItems.json?pid=1', function(data) {
    var items = [];     
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');        
    });

    var result = $('<ul/>', {
         html: items.join('')
    });

    $("#g1").html(result);
});
```

Comment: Вопрос равносилен "как обработать нефть?". Вы что на выходе-то хотите получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По моему проще всего делать как то так:

```js
$.post(url,function(data){
 
    data.items.forEach(function(item){
       str += '<li id="'+item.ide+'">'+item.namesmall+'</li>';
    });

},'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, у вас json не корректный, массив это квадратные скобки []

```
{   
"total": 2,
"module": "content",
"method": "getComplectItems",
"items": [
        {
            "ide": "1",
            "namesmall": "11namr3rfd1",             
            "group": "1gr1"
        },
        {
            "ide": "2",
            "namesmall": "222namr3rfd1",                
            "group": "2gr1"
        }
    ]
}
```

и в скрипте опечатка data и result

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужна рекурсия. Вот как с помощью рекурсии вывести json:

```js
var json={   
"total": 2,
"module": "content",
"method": "getComplectItems",
"items": {
    "item": {
        "0": {
            "ide": "1",
            "namesmall": "11namr3rfd1",             
            "group": "1gr1"
        },

        "1": {
            "ide": "2",
            "namesmall": "222namr3rfd1",                
            "group": "2gr1"
        }
    }
 }
};

$("#g1").html(recursive(json));    

function recursive(data){
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        if(typeof val == 'object'){
            items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + key +':' + recursive(val) + '</li>');
        }else{
          items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + key +':' + val + '</li>');
        }
    });
    var result = '<ul>'+items.join('')+'</ul>';
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="g1">Fail</div>
```

Думаю на базе этого вы уже дойдете до нужного результата сами.

Comment: А зачем jsfiddle? Эти 15 строк кода и здесь поместились бы.